# How to combined similar-named nested classes from a derived and its base class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I was working on a small project where I created standard implementations of add-ons for a system. These standard implementations would set up things like logging, configuration, etc. all in a uniform way. All with maintainability and re-usability in mind.

Now the thing I am struggling with right now is how to handle names of settings. Before I always created a nested class `Settings` in with I declared some const string values like

`public const string BananaSetting = "BananaSetting";`

so I pretty much never could misspell a setting's name ever again.

I however have an base class which should have a setting called DEBUG, to use as a generic debug-enabling setting; but also add-on specific settings, which only exist for that one specific add-on.
Seeing as I base every derived class on the class that has the DEBUG setting nested class, any derived class that tries to declare a similar nested class called `Settings` will trigger a compiler warning:

> DerivedClass.Settings hides inherited member 'BaseClass.Settings'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

But I do not want to hide it. What I would really like to do is combine the two Settings classes into one. Is there any way to do this, or is there an existing design pattern of some sort to do this correctly?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public class Settings
    {
        public const string BananaSetting = "BananaSetting";
    }

    public abstract void BaseAbstractMethod();
    public void BaseMethod()
    {
        // intended use
        var settingValue = settingsDictionary[Settings.BananaSetting];
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public class Settings
    {
        public const string DerivedBananaSetting = "DerivedBananaSetting";
    }

    public override void BaseAbstractMethod()
    {
        // intended use
        var settingValue = settingsDictionary[Settings.BananaSetting];
        var subSettingValue = settingsDictionary[Settings.DerivedBananaSetting];
    }
}
```

Comment: for more clarification Show us some code.

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi I have added the basic idea in code (which causes the compiler warning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the settings class in the derived class `new` because it has the same name as the one in the base class. To be able to access the base settings in the derived class, you also need to inherit the nested settings class:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new class Settings : BaseClass.Settings
    {
        public const string DerivedBananaSetting = "DerivedBananaSetting";
    }
// etc..
```

The rest of your code doesn't change.

Comment: Just to double check, if I were to create another class derived of DerivedClass, and perform that trick again, I would still have access to the BaseClass' settings, right?

Comment: Yes, you would. `DerivedClass.Settings` contains all the public members of `BaseClass.Settings`, if you derive again they are available right up the hierarchy.

Comment: Perfect, just tested this and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about sth. like this:

```
public abstract class SettingBase
{
     public abstract string GetSettingName();

     public abstract SettingBase GetSetting();

     //Shared Properties and Stuff here:
}

public class BananaSetting : SettingBase
{
     public override string GetSettingName()
     {
         return nameof(BananaSetting);
     }

     public override SettingBase GetSetting()
     {
         return this;
     }

     //Banana-Specific Settings go here
}

public class DEBUGSetting : SettingBase
{
     public override string GetSettingName()
     {
         return nameof(DEBUGSetting);
     }

     public override SettingBase GetSetting()
     {
         return this;
     }

     //DEBUG-Specific Settings go here
}


public class Program
{
     public void Demo()
     {
         var settings = LoadSettings();
         foreach(var setting in settings)
         {
             var implementation = setting.GetSetting();
             if(implementation is DEBUGSetting dbg)
             {
                 //access dbg.Properties here
             }
             [...]
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but this would create a class per setting, which would be a bit overkill with the sometimes 60+ settings I can have on the add-ons. Plus I would like the Settings class to be nested if possible so its consts point to settings for that add-on type specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to extend the baseclass with some more settings:

```
public class SettingBase
{
     public SettingDerived()
     {
         _settingNamesWithValues.Add("BananaSetting", new object());
     }

    private Dictionairy<string, object> _settingNamesWithValues = new Dictionairy<string, object>();

    public Dictionairy<string, object>() SettingNamesWithValues
    {
         get
         { 
            return _settingNameWithValue;
         }
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
public class SettingDerived : SettingBase
{
     public SettingDerived()
     {
         _settingNamesWithValues.Add("DerivedBananaSetting", new object());
     }

     private Dictionairy<string, object> _settingNamesWithValues = new Dictionairy<string, object>(); 

     //Hide the base SettingNamesWithValues, as we add the values to the derived collection anyways
     public new Dictionairy<string, object>() SettingNamesWithValues
     {
         get
         { 
            foreach(var keyValue in base.SettingNamesWithValues)
            {
                 _settingNameWithValue.Add(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
            }                  
            return _settingNameWithValue;
         }
     }
}
```

You then could access all settings using theire name.

```
var derived = new SettingsDerived();
var derivedBanana = derived.SettingNamesWithValues["DerivedBananaSetting"];
var banana = derived.SettingNamesWithValues["BananaSetting"];
```

Comment: The dictionary with settings comes from the framework within which I work, so it already allows me to retrieve settings like this. What I am trying to accomplish is to make it so that I cannot misspell the names of the settings because I have them as const strings in my respective Settings class.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any need to have them in the sub classes? You could easily achieve your goal doing the following:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public const string BananaSetting = "BananaSetting";

    public abstract void BaseAbstractMethod();
    public void BaseMethod()
    {
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public const string DerivedBananaSetting = "DerivedBananaSetting";

    public override void BaseAbstractMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason for me to put them in a nested class is for grouping and readability. I originally had them like this, but I couldn't easily spot where I used settings by looking at the code (yes a tiny bit OCD on my part), spotting Settings.BananaSetting is easier due to the color class names get I suppose.

Comment: Understandable, I have marked iakobski's answer as useful, due to his answer being more complete and cleaner as a solution. I'll leave mine here as 'another approach'